# Setting variable for org-mode html export?

Tags: org-mode, html

I am trying to set `org-html-link-org-files-as-html` to `nil` for a single org-file (but have the value equal `t` for all other org files). This is a variable defined in [ox-html](https://github.com/yyr/org-mode/blob/master/lisp/ox-html.el).

```
(defcustom org-html-link-org-files-as-html t
  "Non-nil means make file links to `file.org' point to `file.html'.
When `org-mode' is exporting an `org-mode' file to HTML, links to
non-html files are directly put into a href tag in HTML.
However, links to other Org-mode files (recognized by the
extension `.org.) should become links to the corresponding html
file, assuming that the linked `org-mode' file will also be
converted to HTML.
When nil, the links still point to the plain `.org' file."
  :group 'org-export-html
:type 'boolean)
```

I have tried setting

```
#+OPTIONS: org-html-link-org-files-as-html:nil
```

and setting

```
# -*- org-html-link-org-files-as-html:nil; -*-
```

at the top of the file. Neither work - only works when I set in emacs-lisp

```
(setq org-html-link-org-files-as-html nil)
```

but then this applies to all org files. Can I set it for a single org-file?

Comment: Try: `#+BIND: org-html-link-org-files-as-html:nil`.

Comment: @NickD thanks - `org-export-allow-bind-keywords` also needs to be set to non-nil but then it works - can you please write it as an answer and then I can mark it as correct.

Comment: Done - expanded it a bit and added a ref to the manual.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For variables that cannot be set through the `#+OPTIONS` keyword, the `#+BIND` keyword mechanism can be used. Adding

```
#+BIND: org-html-link-org-files-as-html:nil
```

to the top of your file would be equivalent to your `#+OPTIONS` line if the option existed. `#+BIND` was introduced as a mechanism to set export options without having to set up options explicitly and a priori, as `#+OPTIONS` requires (basically, Carsten Dominik, the creator of org-mode, got tired of having to add more options as user requests were coming in and provided an extensible mechanism). Not everything can be done with `#+BIND` but it is perfect for this use.

The [manual](https://orgmode.org/manual/Export-Settings.html#index-BIND_002c-keyword) says:

> If `org-export-allow-bind-keywords` is non-nil, Emacs variables can become buffer-local during export by using the `‘BIND’` keyword. Its syntax is `#+BIND: variable value`. This is particularly useful for in-buffer settings that cannot be changed using keywords.

See also a related [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41964712/how-does-bind-really-works/42012392#42012392) of mine on this topic.